# Get the date of Sunday and Saturday 2 weeks ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that produces a report each night. This SP references a view that takes a snapshot of data from 2 weeks ago (Sunday to Saturday).

I need to get the dates of the Saturday and Sunday from two weeks ago (so for today that would be 23/24 of December.

I have searched through many solutions but I am unable to find a decent response to this - any one able to help with an answer as well as explaining a little bit of the reason for doing it that way (it seems like there are a thousand ways to do it).

Thanks

Comment: A combination of `dateadd` and 'datename` should get you what you seek.

Comment: @DanBracuk Sorry I wasn't very clear. I am after the actual date.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks @DanBracuk

Comment: It's important when speccing this sort of question to think about the *edge cases*. For instance, if today were not a weekday but was in fact a Saturday or Sunday itself, are you looking for a weekend that occurred almost three weeks ago or just two weeks ago - I.e. when does the answer jump forward by a week? Does it jump on the transition between Friday and Saturday, between Saturday and Sunday, or between Sunday and Monday? Or some other time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer in case any one needs it in future.

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, -2, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6))
```

Comment: I had to remove the `CAST(` to get it to compile, but  
this will not return saturday unitl sunday if getdate() would happen to be another day than monday..

Comment: @DamonSmithies: Very well. +1 by me!

Comment: so if you run this query on a thursday for example, you need the result from thursday unitl friday ? Not from that weeks saterday until sunday ? Just trying to understand the question correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for Saturday) is the same for Sunday:

```
DECLARE @today datetime
SET @today = GETDATE()

SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Monday' THEN DATEADD(day, -15, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Tuesday' THEN DATEADD(day, -16, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Wednesday' THEN DATEADD(day, -17, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Thursday' THEN DATEADD(day, -18, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Friday' THEN DATEADD(day, -19, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(day, -13, @today)
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @today) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(day, -14, @today)
END
```

`DATENAME` with `weekday` parameter returns the name of the day, so if you are on Monday you must subtract 15 days to reach Saturday and so on.

Pay attention: If you have another language set you can change it for your query using:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
```

You can see [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/171971/1/0)

Comment: I think this will not return saturday unitl sunday if getdate() would happen to be another day than monday... For example `SET @today = GETDATE() - 3`

Comment: @GuidoG: Check my SqlFiddle trial

Comment: i just did, it return 17 until 24

Comment: @GuidoG: Question "I need to get the dates of the Saturday and Sunday from two weeks ago" So if I write GETDATE()-3 the query must return 17th (no 24th)

Comment: I see what you mean. But its not clear from the OP question if he runs this query also on other days, for example on a tuesday and on a wednesday... Does he still needs to get saturday unitl sunday from that week ? That is how i understood it

Comment: @GuidoG: I suppose Damon Smithies answer has closed the question. Good answer ;) with one simple row

Answer (score 0):

Since the `day of week` value can differ on different machines you either need to set it using the `set datefirst 1` command as suggeste in Podiluska's answer,
or you can do it by first determining the actual value for sunday and add that to the days you are subtracting.
To determine the actual value for sunday simply ask the value for a know sunday, like 2018-01-07 for example

Below example should return `2017-12-23 / 2017-12-24`
It will also return this if you are running this on friday, or thursday, or whatever day...

```
-- this will contain are test date
declare @date date = getdate() - 2

-- determine the number for sunday
declare @Sunday int = (select datepart(dw, '20180107'))

select convert(date,dateadd(d, -15 - datepart(dw, @date) + (datepart(dw, @date) - @Sunday), getdate())), 
       convert(date,dateadd(d, -14 - datepart(dw, @date) + (datepart(dw, @date) - @Sunday), getdate()))
```

Answer (score -1):

That depends on how you define when your week starts, but the basic principle is to find the start of this week, and take away 14 days.

eg:

```
set datefirst 1

select convert(date,dateadd(d, -15-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate())), 
   convert(date,dateadd(d, -14-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate()))
```

Comment: if you dont want to use the `datefirst` command you could get the number for sunday from a known sunday (like 20180107) and subtract that value

Comment: this will not return saturday unitl sunday if getdate() would happen to be another day than monday...

Comment: @GuidoG Yes, it will

Comment: try it with getdate() - 3

Comment: @GuidoG getdate()-3 returns the Saturday and sunday for the previous week. Which is what you'd expect.

Comment: it does not on my sql server

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'll work on a general form for these; this is the quick and dirty.
I like the NEXT_DAY function. Simple, and obvious as to what it does.

```
    declare  
  vFromDate date :=  trunc( sysdate ) - 9 ; -- '27 Feb 2019'  
  vSatDate  date ;  
  vSunDate  date ;  
begin  
  -- test a range of dates  
  while vFromDate <= sysdate -- '3 Mar 2019'  
  loop  
    select NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( vFromDate) - 21, 'SAT')    -- 7: general form for these?  
    -- keep or discard the " - 1" depending on if the 2 wk Sunday is the desired Sunday  
         , NEXT_DAY ( TRUNC ( vFromDate) - 20 - 1, 'SUN') -- 1:  
         into vSatDate, vSunDate  
         from dual ;  
    dbms_output.put_line( to_char( vFromDate, 'dd Mon": "' )   
                        || to_char( vSatDate, 'dd Mon' )   
                        || to_char( vSunDate, '", "dd Mon' )  
                        );  
    vFromDate := vFromDate + 1 ;  
  end loop ;  
  dbms_output.put_line( rpad('*', 21, '*' ) );  
end ;
```